# MongoDB slow performance when fetching large array of documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So I've been at this for a week now and I can't solve it. Queries for large arrays of documents are way too slow.

I'm running a super basic find query followed by a `.toArray()` and then sending it to our frontend.

```js
const orders = await db.collection('Orders').find({ organization: new ObjectId('5fa28c7ad882490116f8761e') }).toArray()
```

The query itself takes 25 milliseconds seen below in the **executionStats** but before the data is retrieved it takes 4.5 seconds.

A couple of hundred documents work as expected, it takes a couple of hundred milliseconds tops. But over 500 documents it quickly slows down and now I'm at a 4.5 seconds fetch for ~25k documents. And this is not even the final query. I'm going to a run an aggregation with a few steps on top of this, but this seem to be the main issue, and it just can't be hardware related. I've tried to bump upp the database to an M60 instead of an M30 mentioned below, almost no difference, and it's way too expensive for our company size.

What can I do? Is MongoDB just unable to return anything more than a few hundred documents?

---

Here's some stats:

- **Database**: Hosted at MongoDB Atlas with the server in the same country, Cluster size M30 (8 GB RAM, 100 GB storage, 2 vCPUs, 288 IOPS). Up to 10 GBit/s network.
- **My machine**: 64 GB 3600 MHz RAM, 5950x CPU, 970 EVO Plus M.2 SSD. 150 MBit/s network.
- **Collection stats**:

```json
{
    "ns" : "[db].Orders",
    "size" : 207216190,
    "count" : 467771,
    "avgObjSize" : 442,
    "storageSize" : 59006976,
    "freeStorageSize" : 12288,
    "capped" : false,
    "wiredTiger" : {
        "metadata" : {
            "formatVersion" : 1
        }
    }

}
```

- **Execution stats**:

```json
{
    "executionSuccess": true,
    "nReturned": 26385,
    "executionTimeMillis": 25,
    "totalKeysExamined": 26385,
    "totalDocsExamined": 26385,
    "executionStages": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "nReturned": 26385,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 3,
        "works": 26386,
        "advanced": 26385,
        "needTime": 0,
        "needYield": 0,
        "saveState": 26,
        "restoreState": 26,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "docsExamined": 26385,
        "alreadyHasObj": 0,
        "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "nReturned": 26385,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 2,
            "works": 26386,
            "advanced": 26385,
            "needTime": 0,
            "needYield": 0,
            "saveState": 26,
            "restoreState": 26,
            "isEOF": 1,
            "keyPattern": {
                "organization": 1,
                "state.removed": 1
            },
            "indexName": "organization_1_state.removed_1",
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "multiKeyPaths": {
                "organization": [],
                "state.removed": []
            },
            "isUnique": false,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 2,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": {
                "organization": [
                    "[ObjectId('5fa28c7ad882490116f8761e'), ObjectId('5fa28c7ad882490116f8761e')]"
                ],
                "state.removed": [
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
            },
            "keysExamined": 26385,
            "seeks": 1,
            "dupsTested": 0,
            "dupsDropped": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The query stats show a time of **25ms** for 26k documents returned. Where are you getting the 4 seconds? Is it including network? Possibly to code running on your local machine? It looks like 26K docs is about 10MB, which could be a slow internet connection

Comment: The 4 seconds is on my machine. I'm running the line of code on my Node.js backend server on localhost. If it's network related, then it must be choking somewhere at MongoDB. It says up to 10GBit/s on my cluster and I'm currently getting 150MBit/s here at my office (just ran another test), I should be able to fetch everything in 1 second tops.

Comment: Yes, with that speed it should be less than a second for network. MongoDB is fine with these sort of queries. I don't think there is an upper limit other than what you can fit in memory before returning from the server. How are you measuring the time - is it in the browser to display the data? It's best to use `process.hrtime()` around the query. https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.0/api/all.html#all_process_hrtime

Comment: I used console.time right before the query and console.timeEnd right after and it said 4.531 seconds. I'm measuring the speed on my backend and watching the result in the terminal. hrtime would give around the same values most likely.

Comment: It looks like you are doing everything right. I'm not used to using the `collection...toArray()` format, maybe try `Model.where()` in case there is a difference. I would suggest running the same code on an EC2 instance in the same one as the MongoDB Atlas, and possibly even adding the EC2 to the same VPC. Otherwise I can recommend the Atlas support, they are very helpful.

Comment: That 4 seconds might also include the time take to establish a new connection to the database, which might include multiple round trips for authentication and status check.  Turn up the verbosity of the logging in the mongod to get the exact timing of everything.

Comment: @Joe If I do a query of one document i'm looking at a total of ~50 ms query time, so the authentication status check seem to work perfectly. Would that time increase with the number of documents for some reason? I've established an open connection pool to my backend.

Comment: @caffeinated.tech https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/find/ It returns a cursor which needs to be iterated, in my scenario .toArray() is the most relevant. I tried to find any information to skip the cursor fetch and build the complete array in MongoDB and return one complete array instead of a iterable cursor, but I could not find any information on this.

I've also pushed the query to my production environment which is located in the same data center as our Atlas server and the time was reduced to 4 instead of 4.5 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using mongoose for some reason. The way you are fetching is correct. The more I think about it, 4s for 26K documents returned isn't that odd. I rarely fetch more than 500 at a time, and then use pagination for more. If you are aggregating this data, and not returning the full 26K, then I think it will be a lot faster. I'm guessing, but I reckon a lot of time is spent in serializing / deserializing the data

Comment: @Joe It might actually be network related after all, for some reason, the query is not using my full network speed. But when i reduced the document size with a *project* and peered my VPC with Atlas for my production environment at AWS it improved a lot. I'll keep playing around and see if that is the root cause. Thanks

Comment: @caffeinated.tech Maybe the solution would be to load chunks. The reason i want to load all those documents is because i want to make everything searchable at the front end. But i could chunk load it as a lazy load and use Atlas Search search engine instead. I'll play around and see what I can achieve. Thanks

Comment: Hi @JonathanNielsen, did you ever found a solution? I am experiencing the same issue and `toArray()` is the culprit...

Comment: @Edgar I think so, but I'm still not sure. I think the issue is that MongoDB is deserializing the raw data into BSON before sending back which takes a lot of resources, and the Atlas servers doesn't have the best CPU power. I managed to speed up my requests a lot by choosing to receive the raw data and deserializing the data on my server instead (check the bson repo for instructions). It takes a lot more resources of my server, but that's not an issue. The cost increase for my CPU is negligible compared to increasing the cpu power in Atlas.

Comment: @Edgar I also chunked the requests into chunks of 1k-10k documents per request and sent everything at the same time with `await Promise.all`. This way i sped up a 30-60 sec request down to like 2-3 seconds. About 50k very chunky documents.